# Error reporting when sending emails with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, error-reporting, airbrake, exception-notifier

What's the proper way to get error reports, when using a tool like AirBrake or ExceptionNotifier from mailing delayed jobs?

I tried to creating my own delayed job class, but the mail object created by `Mailer.welcome()` (or similar) is not serialized correctly. I also tried adding an `error(job, exception)` method to the `PerformableMailer` and `PerformableMethod` classes, but I got more errors generally related to serializing I believe. I tried both psych and sych for the serialization.

Comment: Have you tried anything like this way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683364/how-to-make-delayed-job-notify-airbrake-when-an-actionmailer-runs-into-an-error

Comment: Posted updated solution, can you pls check? It ended up being a simple class-method instead of an object-method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Updated Solution

Overall the solution is quite simple. If you have are doing delayed_job on an *Object* (like `MyClass.new.delay.some_method`), then you need to define error handling as an object method. If you're doing delayed_job on a *Class* (like `MyTestMailer.test_email ...`), then you need to define error handling as a class method.

Let's say you have a mailer called `TestMailer`. The solution is to define the error handling as a *class method*, not an *object method*:

```
# Your rails mailer
class TestMailer

  # Whoa! error has to be a class method!
  def self.error(job, e)
    puts "I can now handle test mailer errors in delayed job!!!!"
  end

end
```

Now the above `def self.error` method will be used as the error callback in the delayed job!

Or if you want to be able to handle all action mailer errors,

```
class ActionMailer::Base
  def self.error(job, e)
    puts "I can now handle all mailer errors in delayed job!!!"
  end
end
```

The reason is because of the way DelayedJob's internal `PerformableMethod` handles errors. A `PerformableMethod` has two things: a Target Object, and a Target Method.  In Action Mailer's case, the Target Object is not an object, but your mailer class `TestMailer`. The target method is the mail method that you use, say `test_mail`. DelayedJob looks for all the hooks (`error`, `before`, `after`, etc) on the Target Object. But in our case, the Target Object is the class itself. Hence the hooks have to be defined as class methods.

The way `DelayedJob` handles ActionMailer mails is a little hacky. If you add an object method instead of a class method, it throws an unwanted exception. For example, here is the code:

```
# In <delayed-job-gem>/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb
module Delayed
  class PerformableMethod

    # line #7
    delegate :method, :to => :object
```

Every object in ruby has a `method` function, which is used to get a raw reference to a method inside that class. But in DelayedJob - this raw `method` function has been kind of delegated to some other target object. This hack prevents us from normally using the `def error` function for handling job errors.

Edit: Added footnote, minor clarification

Edit 2: Reordered answer

Comment: Awesome response! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great answer.  If you want to track errors on *all* jobs, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14172132/1842747

Answer (score 2):

First, a module for inclusion in mailer and, possibly, other delayed jobs:

```
module Delayed
  module Airbrake
    # Send error via Airbrake
    def error(job, e)
      ::Airbrake.notify(e, :component => job.name, :action => 'perform', :parameters => {:job => job.inspect})
    end
 end
```

end

then include it:

```
Delayed::PerformableMailer.send(:include, Delayed::Airbrake)
```

Comment: When I tried that, I got this error: undefined method `error' for class `Class'
.../gems/delayed_job-3.0.5/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:7:in `method'